# Shouldn't there be a 'quantum-information' tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

As a beginning student of quantum computing, I'm finding many of the questions here that start out seeming relevant to me have answers that veer off into too much physics. Quantum information and quantum computing have their own idioms that are easily overwhelmed by the associated physics, especially its much more complex mathematics.

Shouldn't we have a `quantum-comutation` or `quantum-information` tag to identify questions that are focused on the distinct mathematics of these disciplines?

Comment: Woudn't such questions be more suitable for Physics SE?

Comment: @ramanujan_dirac: No, certainly not. That's the whole point: the questions are often *not* about physics, but they attract physicsy answers, which are unhelpful.

Comment: Sure! Go ahead and create the tag! A couple remarks: [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com) seems to have these tags already, so do check it out first, whether that is a more suitable SE-forum. Correct me if I'm wrong, but or a tag to survive in the long run don't we need a minimum of a few dozen questions using that tag? So it might be a good idea to have a plan B. At least write a tag-wiki describing alternative/related tags (one of the higher rep users will surely approve a tag-wiki edit).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Theoretical CS SE is pretty much closed to mere mortals like me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Yes, their charter indicates that they only welcome research level questions. But at least in the case of coding theory (the only tag I ever follow at CSTheory.SE) the questions seem to typically come from the practicing electrical engineers. I do understand why you might be awed there - Peter Shor does post there.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, I think this would be a useful tag.

As for the name, I have a weak preference for `quantum-computation`.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask a question about quantum computation/information, you have the [ability to add these tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/create-tags), even if they don't currently exist.  The fact that these tags do not exist here might simply mean that such questions have not yet been asked (though I am aware of at least one researcher in quantum computation/information that frequents this site).

Comment: It is still good practice to ask on meta before starting a new tag.

Comment: Yes, that's the question.